# CentOS machine lost its domain name

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have a CentOS 5.5 machine and it has a domain name assigned to it and all of a sudden that domain name is gone and it shows its domain name as "fqdn". the login shows as [root@fqdn] and "hostname" command returns "fqdn". any idea whats going wrong here ? or what should I be looking for in this case.

By the way I have some errors in my dmesg

```
type=1400 audit(1345154461.224:5387): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=13584 comm="ip" path="/tmp/netchklog" dev=dm-0 ino=393854 scontext=user_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=file
type=1400 audit(1345154521.247:5388): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=14104 comm="ip" path="/tmp/netchklog" dev=dm-0 ino=393854 scontext=user_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Answer (score 0):

FQDN stands for Fully Qualified Domain Name, apparently someone reset it to some default.

You can reset it with:

```
# hostname <hostname>
```

as root of course.

Note though that this has nothing to do with any DNS A/CNAME records you might have.

Comment: No one  touches these machines. I knew I can change the name back, but  I am trying to figure out why this happened before I reset the name or reboot the box.

Comment: Have you considered an attack / rootkit ?

Comment: No. It doesn't look like it had a attack. I reset my hostname back, but still its a mystery on how it got changed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all CentOS 5.5 is pretty EoL. Current version is 5.9 - so this might have been a successful attack on your system.

Second - check your dhcp-settings. It might be that you set it so it automatically changes the fqdn. Has anything changed on your dhcp-server?

`/etc/sysconfig/network` is the place where the hostname is set reboot-safe. When was it last modified? Try to correlate this date/time to other events.